# Git LFS remote deployment

Tags: git, git-lfs, git-deploy

I use Git primarily for deploying websites. Often these websites contain a lot of images in them.

I then use a git push to deploy the website. On the server the website should be hosed on, I have a `post-receive` hook that runs Grunt.js to create different sizes of images as well as minifies css and js etc.

I would like to use Git LFS to store the master versions of the image now so that they don't have to be tracked in the main repository.

I have set up git-lfs locally on my development machine but when doing git push, the large files don't get sent to the server (as far as I can tell).

I also keep a copy of everything in a BitBucket repo and it seems to work fine.

Could you please advise me on how to set up my server so that it will receive the LFS files and put them where I expect them in the git work tree?

Comment: What is the size of one image? 10 MB? How many images do you commit?

Comment: @qräbnö  It varies from project to project.  The one i am working on now is quite image intensive, I imagine I'll have upwards of 20 large images, each probably coming in at around the 4/5 MB mark

Comment: If they change not that often, you do not need Git LFS at all? I do not have experience with LFS, so all I can do, is upvote your question.